# Comparing 2 server lists in excel and Having a new spreadsheet/column created with the values that are not on both sheets

Tags: excel, list, compare

I have 2 large server lists. One list is mine and another is a priority list of servers to get AD working on. I would like to compare the two lists so i can tell which servers on the priority list have had the AD software loaded on them(my list has these servers + others). The end result would hopefully be a new column/spreadsheet with the servers not on my list but that are on the priority list so i know what work still needs to be done. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

More info on your layout would have been useful but:

- My [Duplicate Master adddin](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_2123-Eliminating-duplicate-data-with-Duplicate-Master-V2.html) has a "Unique Items (occur only once option") that will list any items that occur only once. The addin can extract either unique cells, unique rows, or rows based on certain unique columns. It will also handle case sensitivity / whitespaces /regexp string matching
- Chip Pearson provides formulaetechniques for extracting items that [occur in one list but not another here](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ListFunctions.aspx)

[image: duplicate master sample]